# Simplifying class design when I cannot use pure virtual function because of templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have two classes `A` and `B` as follows both implementing a method `g` (repeating the same script in both) which depend on a templated method `f`. How can I avoid repeating the code in `g` method of classes `A` and `B`?

```
class A {
public: 
    template<typename T>
    void f() {} 

    void g() {
        f<int>();
        f<double>();
        // etc.
    }
};

class B {
public: 
    template<typename T>
    void f() {} 

    void g() {
        //The same scipt as that of A::g() 
        f<int>();
        f<double>();
        // etc.
    }
};
```

If `f` were not templated, then I would move `g` to a base class, define a pure virtual function `f` and simplify `A` and `B` as follows:

```
class Base {
public: 
    virtual Base() = default;
    virtual void f() = 0;   
    void g() { f(); }
};

class A : public Base {
public: 
    void f() {} 
};

class B : public Base {
public: 
    void f() {} 
};
```

But, I wonder if there is a similar approach when `f` is templated.

Comment: I don't think there is a good solution to your problem the way you presented it. It seems to me, however, that you have locked on to a certain direction for your solution that may now be the best one. Please explain what it is that you are trying to do this for.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh This is a simplified version of what I have in my design, and my goal is to avoid code repetition.

Answer (score 2):

CRTP works fine here.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
template<typename D>
class X {
public:
    void g() {
        D &d = static_cast<D&>(*this);
        d.template f<int>();
        d.template f<double>();
        // etc.
    }
};

class A: public X<A> {
public: 
    template<typename T>
    void f() { } 
};

class B: public X<B> {
public: 
    template<typename T>
    void f() { }
};

int main() {
    B b{};
    b.g();
}
```

As long as `f` is public in your derived classes, it's a nice solution.
Otherwise, you have to add these ugly `friend class` statements in those classes:

```
class A: public X<A> {
private:
    friend class X<A>;

    template<typename T>
    void f() { } 
};

class B: public X<B> {
private:
    friend class X<A>;

    template<typename T>
    void f() { }
};
```

Comment: I thought of using CRTP but I couldn't make it work in my real code. I should have tested on some toy examples. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Make `g` a non-member function template.

```
template<typename T>
void g(T& v) {
    v.f<int>();
    v.f<double>();
}
```

Then you can pass either an `A` or a `B` to it. If you need access to private members, you can make it a friend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I currently define a `g_helper` function exactly the same as you suggested, and call this from the member `g` function as `g_helper(*this)` but I thought maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure how you quantify better, or why you would consider something wrong with that solution such that there is any reason to seek an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment to @Benjamin Lindley's answer, I had the following solution, which I decided to use in my real code. I believe it's simple, avoids duplicate code, and the implementation of `g_helper` can be hidden in the cpp file.

```
template<class T>
void g_helper(T& t) {
    t.template f<int>();    
    t.template f<double>();
    // etc.
}

class A {
public: 
    template<typename T> 
    void f() {} 

    void g() {
        g_helper(*this);
    }
};

class B {
public: 
    template<typename T>
    void f() {} 

    void g() {
        g_helper(*this);
    }
};
```